# How can I prevent jerky scrolling of UIScrollView if I have calculations in EndDecelerating,EndDragging and DidScroll?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, smooth-scrolling, contentoffset

I have to update text of a label every time I scroll the UIScrollView...or everytime I scroll and leave it stop at a point on it's own. This updation of the text of the label is done based on the contentoffset of the scrollview. So now I am putting checks in each method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     int one = scrollView.contentOffset.x/21;
     int two = (21*one)+14;
     CGPoint point = CGPointMake(two, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
     [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
     [self setLabelText:@"scroll"];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    int one = scrollView.contentOffset.x/21;
    int two = (21*one)+14;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(two, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
    [self setLabelText:@"scroll"];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (offset.x < minuteScrollMinX) offset.x = minuteScrollMinX;
    if (offset.x > minuteScrollMaxX) offset.x = minuteScrollMaxX;
    scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
}
```

Now after this, my scrollview becomes too jerky, how can I prevent this jerky scrolling of the scrollview? Is there a common delegate instead of these three methods or even the top two methods?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe reassigning the contentOffset all the time is not making it happy, try make it that it only gets reassigned if the offset actually changes (in `scrollViewDidScroll:`). looks to me like this should be fine though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculations here shouldn't mess up your scrolling. The trouble is caused by a conflict between the top two methods:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

You need to check the `willDecelarate` argument in the first method. If it is true, do nothing  - `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` will get called eventually. If it is false, do the calc here. When `willDecelarate` is true you are calling your calculation from both methods, which messes up the scroll.

As the calulations are the same in both cases, you can also factor them out to a common method.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
         [self calculateScrollOffset];
    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                      willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
    {
        if (!decelerate) {
             [self calculateScrollOffset];
             }
    }


- (void) calculateScrollOffset
{
    int one = scrollView.contentOffset.x/21;
     int two = (21*one)+14;
     CGPoint point = CGPointMake(two, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
     [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
     [self setLabelText:@"scroll"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..you made my day :)
jerky reduced by more than 40%...rest I am trying to minimize the calculation inside each method.