# After adding and updating sticky with stretchy header in tableView, its scroll becomes jerky

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, header, swift4, sticky

I am developing a custom tableView with stretchy headerView and it also has sticky headerView.

I have successfully achieved it by updating its contentInset and contentOffset properties. But after updating its contentInset the scroll becomes jerky.

Below is the code for the same:
I have added below code in `viewDidLoad` method of viewController.and called another method `updateHeaderView` to update headerView Height and y position. And `kTableHeaderHeight` is the constant tableView header height.

```
    headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight))
    headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    tableView.addSubview(headerView)

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kTableHeaderHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight)
```

In `updateHeaderView` method I have added code:

```
var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)
    var insetTop: CGFloat = 0
    if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight {
        headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
        headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
        insetTop = kTableHeaderHeight
    }else if tableView.contentOffset.y >= 0 {
        insetTop = 0
    }else if tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0{
        insetTop = -tableView.contentOffset.y
    }
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetTop, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetTop, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    headerView.frame = headerRect
```

And called above method from scrollView's delegate method `scrollviewDidScroll`.

After doing all this stuff the sticky and stretchy tableView behavior is as expected but the tableView scroll becomes jerky. And just for the information, I don't want to use any third party library.

Other Methods used for the class

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if (indexPath.row % 2) == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderViewCell") as! HeaderViewCell

        return headerCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 53.0
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.updateHeaderView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get the other methods as well?

Comment: check it : https://medium.com/@jeremysh/creating-a-sticky-header-for-a-uitableview-40af71653b55

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752216/how-do-i-build-a-parallax-style-stretchy-table-view-header-with-an-image-in-it-w

Comment: @RoyFalk, I have added the other methods

Comment: @user1374, I want both stretchy header and one sticky header in the tableView.

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/17482713/5276890 they only change the contentOffset. You’re doing more and that may be the cause.

Comment: @RoyFalk, But by only updating contentOffset, I won't get the results which I want. It only gives me the stretchy header, not the sticky header. I have one view which has a label and that view is used as stretchy header and another view which has 3 buttons, that view should be stick to the top view and behave like a sticky header.

Comment: Why not do a sticky header in uiview and add a uitable ?

Comment: @RoyFalk, Can you explain me in detail or give me any example for the same ?

Comment: I need something like this [link](https://gifyu.com/image/pYbw) @RoyFalk

Comment: I'm finally in front of an actual computer (used the app before) and there's stuff I don't understand. start of viewDidLoad you're creating a UIView and immediately overwriting it with tableView.headerView. Also are the two views (stretchy and sticky) different? Could you talk a little about how you implement each or point to a link where you got the idea from?

Comment: @RoyFalk, Actually I have created UIStretchy View using this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS_11_0.html). Then I have added another view that is sticky view using the delegate method of tableView. And yes there are two different views one is used to show stretchy behavior and one which is going to stick to the device's header or on the top of the table.